# PjSIP Callling it from unknown/external thread

Tags: android, pjsip

I'm trying to build pjsip and make a basic phone call by building a cordova plugin in Android. The following function is in a cordova plugin named

> public class PJSIP extends CordovaPlugin{ .... }

```
  private void makeCall(String number,String hostip ) {

String buddy_uri = "sip:"+number+"@"+hostip;
MyAccount account = null;


AccountConfig accCfg = null;
accCfg = new AccountConfig();
accCfg.setIdUri("sip:localhost");
accCfg.getNatConfig().setIceEnabled(true);
accCfg.getVideoConfig().setAutoTransmitOutgoing(true);
accCfg.getVideoConfig().setAutoShowIncoming(true);

MyAccount acc = new MyAccount(accCfg);
account = acc;


MyCall call = new MyCall(account, -1);
CallOpParam prm = new CallOpParam(true);

try {
  call.makeCall(buddy_uri, prm);

} catch (Exception e) {
  call.delete();
  return;
}

currentCall = call;
```

}

What I receive as an error is the following:

> A/libc: ../src/pj/os_core_unix.c:692: pj_thread_this: assertion
>   "!"Calling pjlib from unknown/external thread. You must " "register
>   external threads with pj_thread_register() " "before calling any pjlib
>   functions."" failed

I was checking around and it seems that there is an issue with the garbage collector but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In pjsip, every call must come from a thread known to pjsip.

On your `EndPoint` object there is a method that helps you with that.
Basically, I just created a static method `checkThread` which helps me registering the `currentThread`.

I call this method at the beginning of every method that accesses pjsip objects.
You need to synchronize this method.

```
public static synchronized void checkThread() {
    try {

        if (mEndpoint != null && !mEndpoint.libIsThreadRegistered())
            mEndpoint.libRegisterThread(Thread.currentThread().getName());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.w("SIP", "Threading: libRegisterThread failed: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

And now each of your methods that access sip objects has to look like:

```
public void makeCall(String number) {
    checkThread();
    //...do your stuff...
}
```

Hope this helps, Cheers.

Comment: Hi Grisgram. Thanks for your comment. Actually the error was different, but you helped me to find some path. I hadn't initialise activity at all and any observer, but it seems that I also need what you mentioned.

Comment: Happy if I could help. A nice way to say "thank you" is to accept the answer if it fixes your thread problem. Thank you.